# tkinter: event binding remains after application terminates?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm running tkinter in Python 3.4. A button event seems to remain bound to a command even after the application terminates. Code snippet:

```
# application class
class DataSel:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        <...>
        self.button_sel = tk.Button(self.parent,text='Select')
        self.button_sel.grid(row=1,sticky='nesw')
        self.button_sel.bind('<Button-1>',self.sel_click)

        self.button_quit = tk.Button(self.parent,text='Quit')
        self.button_quit.grid(row=2,sticky='nesw')
        self.button_quit.bind('<Button-1>',self.quit_click)

    def sel_click(self,event):
        self.filename = askopenfilename(parent=self.parent)
        <...>

    def quit_click(self,event):
        self.parent.destroy()

# main part of application
root = tk.Tk()
root.lift()
sel = DataSel(root)
root.lift()
root.mainloop()
```

When I restart the interpreter from scratch and run this application, there is no error message. However, the `button_sel` button remains pressed (in low relief) after the `sel_click` method is finished. Then, if I quit the application and rerun it, I get the following message in the shell:

```
invalid command name ".94227256"
    while executing
"$w cget -state"
    (procedure "tk::ButtonDown" line 12)
    invoked from within
"tk::ButtonDown .94227256"
    (command bound to event)
```

where the number `.94227256` changes each time I rerun.

Apart from this message, and the fact that the button remains in low relief, all other functionality is OK. But it seems like the button event somehow stays bound to a stale command!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is happening is that your binding happens before the button widget is able to process the same event. You are doing this *during* the processing of the events and you aren't telling Tkinter to stop processing the events further. Therefore, when Tkinter gets around to having the widget process the click event, the window no longer exists and tkinter throws an error.

The root of the problem is that you are putting bindings on a button. You shouldn't do that. If you want to call a function from a button you need to use the `command` attribute of the button.

If you really think you need to do this via a binding (rather than via the `command` attribute), you need your function to return '"break"` to tell tkinter to stop any further processing of the event.

Comment: Odd. I tried using the `command` attribute as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242896/tkinter-button-remains-sunken-when-pressed, but without success. I'll try again.

Comment: OK, I got it. Previously I only tried binding the `button_sel` button with `command`. However, the problem was actually associated with the `button_quit` button. Once I bound that one with `command` the problem went away.

Comment: So is there ever a good time to use a binding with a button? I learned this way of doing it from "Thinking in Tkinter" (http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/tt060_py.txt), which I thought was meant to be a pretty good resource.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski: no, not really. Not unless you want truly custom, non-standard behavior. Buttons already have built-in bindings for button clicks and releases (and a few others) that take care of all the problems such as changing the relief, changing the "active" color, etc. That tutorial contains a really bad example. Putting a custom binding on a button is something you should virtually never do.

Comment: FWIW, "Thinking in Tkinter" does also mention later in [the section tt074.py](http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/tt074_py.txt) that a click is different from a button press and *"(clicking) is a more complicated notion of button invocation than we have used in our previous programs, where we simply bound a "Button-1" event to the button widget using event binding.   Fortunately, there is another form of binding that supports this more complicated notion of widget invocation. It is called "command binding" because it uses the widget's "command" option."*